# the isomorphism of $L^\infty$ spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, von-neumann-algebras

If we have an unitary operator from $L^2(\mathbb{T})$ to $L^2(X,d\mu)$ ,$\mathbb{T}$ is boundary of the unit ball ,$d\mu$is the Borel probability measure.is there an isomorphism between $L^\infty(\mathbb{T})$ to $L^\infty(X,d\mu)$? Many thanks.

Comment: What is $(X,\mu)$? Also, $\mathbb{T}$ usually refers to the boundary of the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$, not the unit ball itself.

Comment: It will require heavy use of the Axiom of Choice.  When $X = \{0,1,2,3,\dots\}$ and $\mu$ is counting measure, then the unitary $L^2$ map is easy (Fourier series, Plancherel's theorem).  But the $L^\infty$ isomorphism requires AC.

Comment: I am sorry,$\mathbb{T}$is the boundary of unit ball of $\mathbb{R^2}$

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, because vaguely speaking localizable measure spaces are nothing more than a commutative von Neumann algebras. For more details see [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20740/is-there-an-introduction-to-probability-theory-from-a-structuralist-categorical-p/20820#20820) on mathoverflow.com.

Comment: Would you mind supplying  a concise proof ?

Comment: No it would take too long

Comment: Is it Borel functional analysis? I don't understand why we need $L^2(\mathbb{T})$ to $L^2(X,d\mu)$ is unitary

Comment: $\mathbb{T}$ is the boundary of unit ball.Consier $\phi:[-1,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{T},\phi(t)=exp^{2l(arcsint+t\sqrt{1-t^2})},t\in\mathbb{T}$. It is easy to check that $L^2(\mathbb{T})\ni f\mapsto f\phi\in L^2([-1,1],\displaystyle\frac{2}{\pi } \sqrt{1-t^2}\mathrm{d}t)$ is a unitary which implements an isomorphism from $L^\infty(\mathbb{T})$ to $L^\infty([-1,1],\displaystyle\frac{2}{\pi } \sqrt{1-t^2}\mathrm{d}t)$(Why?)

Comment: This is another question. Please ask it via standard form. Not in comments.

Comment: I have asked ,but till now nobody can help me.